# How to Specify Images for 4inch iOS devices

Tags: ios

How to Full screen Specify `Images` for `4-inch` `iOS devices`. The `568@2x` will only work for `Default image` Any Approaches will be use full. Please share some code snippet.

Comment: Normal images like which you are using for the iphone4s  app .It is compatable for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that Case, You need can write one category method for UIImage and use that in all places where you need full screen images 
and also mention one

My Naming Convension:

- Normal image: img.png
- Retina image: img@2x.png
- 4inch Screen: img-4@2x.png
- **HEIGHT is Screen Height**

Code:

```
   UIImageView *bgImg = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed5:@"img.png"];
```

Category implementation:

```
+(UIImage *) imageNamed5:(NSString *) imgName
 {

    NSArray *paths =[imgName componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    UIImage *img =nil;
    if(paths.count == 2){
        NSString *imgNme =[paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *ext = [paths objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *imgPath;
        if(HEIGHT == 568)
        {
            imgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",imgNme,@"-4@2x.",ext];
        }
        else
        {
            imgPath = imgName;
        }
        img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgPath];
    }
    if(img == nil){
        img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
    }
    return img;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way

```
Appdelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //check the height of window
   if (delegate.window.frame.size.height == 568)
   {
       //use image_568@2x
   }else{
       //use normal image
   }
```